# During minting of nft ndRestPayload.js:16 if (!url.includes("alchemy")) ^ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Tags: blockchain, nft, ethers.js, hardhat, alchemy

```
 if (!url.includes("alchemy")) {
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')   
    at Object.makeRestPayloadSender (F:\hardhat-nft\node_modules\@alch\alchemy-web3\dist\cjs\web3-adapter\sendRestPayload.js:16:14)
    at Object.makeAlchemyContext (F:\hardhat-nft\node_modules\@alch\alchemy-web3\dist\cjs\web3-adapter\alchemyContext.js:18:40)
    at createAlchemyWeb3 (F:\hardhat-nft\node_modules\@alch\alchemy-web3\dist\cjs\index.js:22:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\hardhat-nft\scripts\mint-nft.js:5:14)   
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)     
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: It is because url is `undefined`.

Comment: got same error. @Ismael hi sherlock. the error is from the node module - not from his code

Comment: ok Ismael was right. soo right. const { ALCHEMY_KEY, PUBLIC_ADDRESS, PRIVATE_KEY, REACT_APP_GAS_LIMIT, REACT_APP_ADDRESS } = process.env;
you are passing the url maybe through env and forgot to set it.

Comment: @Suisse If you need more help create a new question and provide enough details for someone to debug the issue. In this question there's no source, no other information than the error message.

Comment: @Ismael he is using just a code snippet from some tutorial (always same tutorials out there) and they set the url to and contract adresses from an env... I assume he cloned a repo and forgot to create his own env file.